# OAuth authorization in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, httparty

I'm trying to authorize in OAuth. I have to open url in browser. That url redirects me to my application sending auth code.

When I open link in browser everything works fine and I receive the code. When I'm sending get (or post) request from code to that link nothing happens. How can I solve this problem.

Logic: I receive response from OAuth in controller and then send it to service.
Method in controller:

```
def auth_code
  MyService.code(params)
  render json: params
end
```

Method in service:

```
def self.code(params)
  @@code = params['code']
end
```

Sending Request from code (Using Httparty [I tried both post and get] ):

```
code_request = HTTParty.get(code_url)
```

Sending Request from code:

```
code_request = Net::HTTP.get(URI(code_url))
```

P.S. I don't wanna use OAuth gems

Comment: What response do you get when you make the request with HTTParty?

Comment: @alok-swain I'm receiving webpage

Comment: can you try this ? `HTTParty.get(code_url, :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json' })`

Comment: Omniauth solved my problems